# Rank values in grouped data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for an efficient way to re-number the rank vector of a grouped data frame in Python.

In a simple data first I rank the `soldier_type` based on their `counts`. This is simple so far! OTOH, I need to re-rank the soldiers based on the following condition:

if `soldier_type == S1`, in each group of `regiment` and `trucks`, I want it to be always ranked to be `1` and then re-rank other soldier types starting from rank `2` (from highest `counts` to lowest).

Here is my attempt to solve this problem:

```
import pandas as pd

from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint

seed(1234)

raw_data = {'regiment': ['51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st'], 
            'trucks': ['MAZ-7310', 'MAZ-7310', 'MAZ-7310', 'MAZ-7310', 'Tatra 810', 'Tatra 810', 'Tatra 810', 'Tatra 810', 'ZIS-150', 'ZIS-150', 'ZIS-150', 'ZIS-150'],
            'soldier_type': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S1', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5'],            
            'counts': randint(1,100,12)}


df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'trucks','soldier_type', 'counts'])


   regiment     trucks soldier_type  counts
0      51st   MAZ-7310           S1      48
1      51st   MAZ-7310           S2      84
2      51st   MAZ-7310           S3      39
3      51st   MAZ-7310           S4      54
4      51st  Tatra 810           S1      77
5      51st  Tatra 810           S3      25
6      51st  Tatra 810           S4      16
7      51st  Tatra 810           S5      50
8      51st    ZIS-150           S1      24
9      51st    ZIS-150           S2      27
10     51st    ZIS-150           S4      31
11     51st    ZIS-150           S5      44

def rank_soldier_type (df):

    df = df.assign(rank_ = df.groupby(['regiment','trucks'])['counts'].rank(ascending = False,method='dense'))

    return df #1st part
    #%%
    if  df.soldier_type != 'S1' and df.rank_ == 1 :

        df['new_rank_'] = 1
    else:
        df['new_rank_'] = df['rank_'].rank(ascending = False,method='dense')

    return df

df = rank_soldier_type(df)
```

If I run the 1st part of this function I can create `rank_` column:

```
df = rank_soldier_type(df)  

   regiment     trucks soldier_type  counts  rank_
0      51st   MAZ-7310           S1      48    3.0
1      51st   MAZ-7310           S2      84    1.0
2      51st   MAZ-7310           S3      39    4.0
3      51st   MAZ-7310           S4      54    2.0
4      51st  Tatra 810           S1      77    1.0
5      51st  Tatra 810           S3      25    3.0
6      51st  Tatra 810           S4      16    4.0
7      51st  Tatra 810           S5      50    2.0
8      51st    ZIS-150           S1      24    4.0
9      51st    ZIS-150           S2      27    3.0
10     51st    ZIS-150           S4      31    2.0
11     51st    ZIS-150           S5      44    1.0
```

The expected output;

```
        regiment     trucks soldier_type  counts  rank_  new_rank_
    0      51st   MAZ-7310           S1      48    3.0       1.0
    1      51st   MAZ-7310           S2      84    1.0       2.0
    2      51st   MAZ-7310           S3      39    4.0       4.0
    3      51st   MAZ-7310           S4      54    2.0       3.0
    4      51st  Tatra 810           S1      77    1.0       1.0
    5      51st  Tatra 810           S3      25    3.0       3.0
    6      51st  Tatra 810           S4      16    4.0       4.0
    7      51st  Tatra 810           S5      50    2.0       2.0
    8      51st    ZIS-150           S1      24    4.0       1.0
    9      51st    ZIS-150           S2      27    3.0       4.0 
    10     51st    ZIS-150           S4      31    2.0       3.0
    11     51st    ZIS-150           S5      44    1.0       2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code by add `duplicated`

```
df['New']=df[df[['regiment', 'trucks']].duplicated()].\
            groupby(['regiment', 'trucks'])['counts'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense')+1
df.New.fillna(1,inplace=True)
df
Out[35]: 
   regiment     trucks soldier_type  counts  New
0      51st   MAZ-7310           S1      48  1.0
1      51st   MAZ-7310           S2      84  2.0
2      51st   MAZ-7310           S3      39  4.0
3      51st   MAZ-7310           S4      54  3.0
4      51st  Tatra 810           S1      77  1.0
5      51st  Tatra 810           S3      25  3.0
6      51st  Tatra 810           S4      16  4.0
7      51st  Tatra 810           S5      50  2.0
8      51st    ZIS-150           S1      24  1.0
9      51st    ZIS-150           S2      27  4.0
10     51st    ZIS-150           S4      31  3.0
11     51st    ZIS-150           S5      44  2.0
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. Is there any possible to solve this problem like `if-else` fashion as in the OP! I would like to learn how you approach the solution in that case!

Comment: @Alexander if else, so you mean np.where? my solution is to exclude the first row of each group, then we do rank for the rest row, and then just assign 1 to the first row

Comment: Anything works as long as if I can use if else . I prefer that way because I want to apply `rank_soldier_type` with different conditions. So I need a conditionals. np.where is also ok. could you also send your solution in a `def` format ?

Comment: @Alexander when you with pandas, it is better reduce the usage of apply or self-def function, always try use vectorized function in pandas.

Comment: oh really! didn't know that. I though it is more clear code if I just call the self-def function since we can throw many things into and call them!

Comment: @Alexander in term of understanding your solution , Yes , for the efficiency of code no ~